# Appending Files using fopen (C programming language) and the "a+" Mode

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, fopen

I'm having trouble creating files in UTF-8 for appending. The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx) states that using "a+" for the mode parameter opens files for "reading and appending", which is what I need to do. For some reason, when no file exists and I'm creating a new one on the fly, the [BOM or byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) that's created in the new file is malformed.

Basically, it is only writing the first 2 of 3 bytes. It's supposed to write the bytes 0xEF, 0xBB, and 0xBF, but it's only writing the first two (0xEF and 0xBB). If you look at it in a text editor, it should look like this: ï»¿, but looks like this instead: ï». Has anyone seen this? A known fopen bug maybe? This is the code that I'm using to open, and I'm using a simple fwrite to write the file. Everything works fine when I pass in "w" (write) for the mode, but the BOM is malformed for "a" or "a+":

```
_tfopen(PathToFile,UNICODE_CHAR_MACRO("a+, ccs=UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Do you properly close/flush the file?

Comment: Since you refer to "documentation says" that way, I want to clarify something: append mode means, new bytes are always appended to the end of file no matter what, unlike normal write mode. This is probably what you want, saying just in case.

Comment: Yes. I have an extremely simple program that opens the file, prints a Unicode literal string and closes it.

Comment: Why are you using `_tfopen` instead of `fopen`?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Sorry about that. It's actually using _wfopen under the covers, depending on whether or not we're building in Unicode or ANSI.

Comment: Can you post your write statement? I think it's likely the problem is there.

Comment: This question needs repro code and version numbers, not a one-liner that can't even compile.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal fwrite(&buf,sizeof(my_custom_char),len,stdout); // buff is also a my_custom_char and len is an slong

Comment: Well, there goes my suggestion.

Comment: Maybe you should post this as an answer and accept it, so that the question no longer shows up in the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out. The third party software that we're using was actually stripping off the last byte of the BOM, thinking that it was the [ctrl-z MS-DOS end of file character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Z).